# SQL Return Count of Answers with 0's for Choices from another table

Tags: sql-server, join

My question went dead after one unhelpful answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300592/sql-return-count-of-answers-with-0s-for-choices-from-another-table)

I need this to be optimized because it will be called often. It is going into a stored procedure.

```
I am given @slide (tblILDSlide.id) and @sessionid (tblILDSession.id)
```

I need my results to look like this:

```
--lets say students had answered a(3),b(10),c(0),d(5) in a survey (test)
 |Answer Counts 
0|3
1|10
2|0 --this needs to show as a zero and not be skipped
3|5
```

Since questions will each have different numbers of possible answers I need to have the rows seeded from the @@rowcount of Choice for the QID that is here:

```
**dbo.tblSurveyAnswerChoice
 QID (int, not null)
 Sequence (int, null)
 Choice (nvarchar(100), null) --this column will vary and is for choices
 --like true/false, Yes, No, Red Blue, 
 --or even Completely Agree,Somewhat Agree...,Completely Disagree
```

To get the QID I have to use @slide and:

```
**dbo.tblILDSlide
 id (PK, int, not null)
 slide_type(FK, int, not null)
 question_id(FK, int, null)
 media_url(nvarchar(100), null)
```

I need a row for every choice (with zeros for choices with no responses). The responses are kept here:

```
 --there can be more than one response per question 
 --like for multiple-multiple choice (check all that apply)
**dbo.tblResponses
 response_id(FK, int, not null)
 answer_sequence (int, null) --accepts 1,2,3 etc for choice
 other (nvarchar(50), null) --for text answers
```

To get them I have to use response_id which I can get by using @sessionid AND @slide here:

```
**dbo.tblSlideResponseInfo
 id (PK, int, not null)
 user_id(nvarchar(50), not null)
 slide_id (FK, int, not null)
 response_date (datetime, not null)
 session_id (FK, int, not null)
```

**Copied from the post at stackoverflow:**  My problem is when there is a possible choice with no answers I get no count. So I know I need to grab the possible choices which are available [in the other table ...]  I am thinking I need to return a blank row for every answer that exists in the tblSurveyAnswerChoices then somehow join the other counts to that, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This is not going to be close to being an answer, but your question is very difficult to understand. I would consider using Table Variable and a cursor to accomplish it based on what little I really understand.

Comment: Can you add sample input data too please?

Comment: Your question at Stackoverflow is more clear.  I have posted an answer there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300592/sql-return-count-of-answers-with-0s-for-choices-from-another-table

Comment: @krubo I encourage you to post the same answer here. @lazfish I encourage you to try to choose one site for asking questions. However, I'm open to cross-posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(copying my own answer from the same question on StackOverflow)

Your post already includes a good answer:  "I am thinking I need to return a blank row for every answer that exists in the tblSurveyAnswerChoices then somehow join the other counts to that."

Here is one way to do so:

```
select choice, ifnull(countanswervalue,0) 
from tblsurveyanswerchoice
left join 
    (select answer_sequence, count(answer_sequence) as countanswervalue
    from tblslideresponses
    group by answer_sequence) 
    as countanswer on countanswer.answer_sequence=tblsurveyanswerchoice.sequence
/* the where clause is what you already posted */
where qid in (select question_id from tblidslide where id = @slide)
```

The use of `left join` ensures that any choice in the first table will be listed.  By default, left join would return NULL for items not existing in the second table, but `ifnull` lets you replace NULL with 0.

NOTE: `ifnull` in MySQL should be replaced by `isnull` in TSQL